# Python List of Different Strings, add all the words together

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Given List

```
sentence = [ "Hello" , "World", "Today is a good", "Day"]
```

Output should be average of those words, so 1.75

I have this so far

```
for k in len(line): // here i am trying to get position 0,1,2,3etc for k
        total += len(line[k].split())
return total / len(line)
```

The error is: `'int' object is not iterable`, I did look at the same problem on this website, but still don't understand what is the problem. What is a better way of writing this loop?

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over the positions:

```
for k in range(len(line)):
```

Alternatively, iterate over the sentence fragments directly:

```
for fragment in line:
   total += len(fragment.split())
```

Or you can replace the loop with a generator expression:

```
total = sum(len(fragment.split()) for fragment in line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for k in len(line):
```

with

```
for k in range(len(line)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join+split and then divide by the length of the list

```
>>> sentence = [ "Hello" , "World", "Today is a good", "Day"]
>>> float(len(" ".join(sentence).split()))/len(sentence)
1.75
```

In Python2, you need to make one of them a float otherwise the division truncates.

Comment: This is a better way to do it, but it's far more complex than what he's looking for - and it doesn't point out what the problem in his code is...

Answer (score 0):

Given your sentence:

```
sentence = ["Hello", "World", "Today is a good", "Day"]
```

You can make it as a one liner:

```
print(sum((len(word.split()) for word in sentence))/float(len(sentence)))
```

But to easily understand it look at this code:

```
sentence = ["Hello", "World", "Today is a good", "Day"]
word_counts = [len(word.split()) for word in sentence] # make a list of word counts
# [1, 1, 4, 1]
print sum(word_counts)/float(len(sentence))
# 1.75
```